# Divide and conquer algorithm to find the counterfeit coin in O(logn)

Tags: algorithm, runtime, recurrence, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

[image]

Hi !! I tried to find information and examples to solve this problem but couldn't find it.. This is my preparation questions for exam and not assignment.Could someone explain the steps to solve this problem? And, any resource with related examples like this? cheers!!

Comment: Not actually solvable for n = 2. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the solution in (log2(n) + 1) steps. `+1` is to find whether heavy or light. If you know that part, it will take log2(n) steps.

Divide into 2 piles. Say, A and B. Weigh them against each other, and you find `A<B` (read, weight of pile A is lesser then that of B). Take a pile, say A, split and weigh the parts. If they weigh equal, you get 2 facts:

- Counterfeit coin is in B
- It is heavier than other coins.

And then you continue with pile B. (and there went your `+1` weighing.)

otherwise:

- Counterfeit coin is in A
- It is lighter than other coins.

Now, say A contained counterfeit coin. Then, name the two divided piles of A as `A and B`, and, repeat.

PS: I solved this puzzle with 3^n coins to start (a few years back). It also takes same number of steps, as its complexity is (log3(n) (+1)). I'll leave it as your next question to solve.

PPS: I'll leave the second part of the question to you. Apply `Master's theorem` yourself. 
HINT: Same as that of `binary search`.